# How do i write a code that close half position?

Tags: mql5

```
        int closeHalf=0;
        while(closeHalf==0){
           if(AccountInfoDouble(ACCOUNT_PROFIT)>=5.0){
              if(glBuyTicket>0 || glSellTicket>0)Trade.Close(_Symbol,0.005,NULL);
           }
        closeHalf =1;
        }
```

i want to close half of the lot size when profit has reached $5 and i want it to run once. what i observe is, if the profit has reached $5 instead of closing half lot size it is opening opposite trade (if current trade is buy and on profit it will now open sell).

Comment: indeed, this is how MT5 works in netting mode. When it opens half of the opposite position, the netting position decreases. You do not have to pay swaps, and marginal requirements decrease, so this is correct close.

Comment: Thank you very much